# How should the Hbase data should be for fast query response?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, cassandra, hbase

I have a situation with the following rules :

1. A user can only be at one venue at a time. If user A checks in at venue X and then at
   venue Y, they are no longer at venue X.
2. A check-in only “lasts” for at most 3 hours. If user A checks in at venue X and then does
   nothing for 3 hours, they are no longer at venue X.

The data will be parsed into HBase using Kafka and spark-streaming.

I want to use HBase with TTL is 3 hours and versioning is 1 which meets the above conditions. The problem is I am confused how to organize the data in HBase for faster query response, should I use a single column with venue names or venue names as different column names?

Which will be a better option and why?

Queries needed to perform are:
1. Where is user A right now?
2. What users are at venue X right now?

Comment: how many users and how many venues are expected? what is read-write ratio? how many requests per second are expected?

Comment: This is a new implementation for real-time queries. Everything will be less at the moment but expect every public spot as a venue.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient query is based on **row key** of HBase table.
I would use user name as row key to be able quickly get info where is particular user. And you'll need one column for each row - venue.

Obviously, to collect all data (query 2: what users are at venue X) you'll need to scan whole (part) of table. So it won't be very efficient. Take a look into secondary indexes for HBase - if you face performance issues with such queries.

Answer (score 1):

So, to address above scenario I would suggest having two table:

1. The row key of the first table will be userID (I would also suggest adding some shard key like (userID % number of HBase regions) to evenly distribute data and avoiding hot spotting). This table will provide mapping userID -> venue, and checking where is particular user will take O(1).
2. The row key for the second table will be venueID + userID (also prefixed with some shard key). Thus, you can user KeyOnlyFilter and PrefixFilter (prefix is venue) to get all users in a specific venue. This should be quite fast.

Since you use Kafka and Spark, ingesting to two tables should not affect your performance.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Nice approach. But do you think it is worth two tables?

Comment: The main overhead of this type of denormalization are updates. But as I understand in you case updates are done during injestion,and simultaneously. So you can keep data in sync in both tables. So, I think this should work.